# Django sqlite3 custom sql operational error when passing more than one parameter

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to run a custom sql query in django on an sqlite3 database and get an operational error when I try and pass more than one parameter into my sql statement. I'm not sure why, I've tried using cursor.fetchall() instead of namedtuplefetchall but that didn't work. My database is named cardholders.sqlite3 and I have a table also name cardholders that I'm trying to pull data out of.

below is the relevant code

```
from django.db import connections
from collections import namedtuple
def namedtuplefetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a namedtuple"
    desc = cursor.description
    nt_result = namedtuple('Result', [col[0] for col in desc])
    return [nt_result(*row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

then some views in between

```
@login_required
def databaseTest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postid = request.POST.get("id")
        with connections['cardholders'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ID = %s",['cardholders',postid])
            row = namedtuplefetchall(cursor)
            cursor.close()
        return render(request, 'LibreBadge/databaseTest.html',
        context = {"AlertMessage":AlertMessage.objects.all, "row":row})
        row = "none"
    else:
        return render(request, 'LibreBadge/databaseTest.html',
        context = {"AlertMessage":AlertMessage.objects.all})
```

and the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/databaseTest/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['LibreBadge',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (near "?": syntax error) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/micah/Documents/GitHub/LibreBadge/mysite/LibreBadge/views/views.py", line 27, in databaseTest
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ID = %s",['cardholders',postid])
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/micah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /databaseTest/
Exception Value: near "?": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead do:

```
            qry = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ID = ?".format('cardholders')
            cursor.execute(qry,(postid,))
```

Query parametrization doesn't work for table names thus the need for two separate operations with the query string.

Also the `with` statement is going to close the `cursor` itself so you do not need this line:

```
            cursor.close()
```

Comment: would it be a bad idea to do qry =  "SELECT * FROM" + table + " WHERE" + field + " =" 
 +value ? with all table field and value as variables

Comment: Thank you so much this was driving me nuts

Comment: is there a good way to prevent sql injection here by escaping the variables?

Comment: I suggest making a whitelist of tablenames, and check for membership in that list.

Comment: I mean for other parameters passed as variables like the value variable that I used below

Comment: Oh for the values they should be substituted in with the database module's facility for that; in this case with the `?` like is shown in my answer.

Comment: In my app, librebadge (librebadge.com), I am going to have users submit a json file with table names and field mappings to databases that the user has created with a tool like omnidb. Should I be worried about users passing in values that might break an sql database? If so, how could I escape the table name?. The above comment solved my current issue btw

Comment: Oh, absolutely you should be worried. I'm actually wondering now why you're not using the ORM in Django? That would handle SQL injection, I believe.

Comment: my project is an ID badge solution where users have to be able to define fields and constraints at run time which django orm can't do without a lot of work afaik so I opted to just use custom sql as I could easily use that and a json file to map to user created databases (separate from the app's internal sqlite db)

Comment: I see what you're saying. One thing might be to dump the table- and column-names into a file, and then check membership in that file before running each query. Seems less than ideal, though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212997/discussion-between-memtech3-and-mechanical-meat).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you mechanical_meat for helping me this is the code that I wrote as a result of your answer

```
from django.db import connections
from collections import namedtuple

def namedtuplefetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a namedtuple"
    desc = cursor.description
    nt_result = namedtuple('Result', [col[0] for col in desc])
    return [nt_result(*row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

def select(db, table, field, value):
    with connections['cardholders'].cursor() as cursor:
                qry = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + field + " = " + value
                cursor.execute(qry,[])
                return namedtuplefetchall(cursor)
                cursor.close()
```